# Simple Javascript for loop stops after first iteration

Tags: javascript

I've read a bunch of other posts that have had similar issues and still can't figure out why this one is being weird. I tried doing try/catch and no errors were reported. The arrays are actually 100+, but narrowing it down for the example. It works when searching for the first item in the array, but all after that it fails after one iteration attempt. I printed out the array length and it is seeing that the array is over 100 in length.

Edit: I should note that this is the only place a var k is used.

```
function main(){
  var list = [["feature 123", 5.0], ["feature 234", 38.0], ["feature 345", 38.0]];
  var search = "feature 234";
  var a = getIndexx(list, search);
}

function getIndexx(array, str) {
   for(var k=0; k < array.length; k++) {
     if(array[k][0] === str) {
       return k;
     } else {
       return -1
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You’re returning in the for loop, which breaks out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `return -1` inside the for loop, which means if it finds the match on the first index it'll return `0` otherwise it'll immediately return `-1`. You want to move the `return -1` so it's after the for loop, so if it finds no matches it returns -1.

Comment: Omg, I feel like an idiot. Thank you!!! I'll mark this as the answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want an `else` condition. You only want to return the found index if the condition is valid.

If you did not find a matching value, while looping, then you return `-1`.

```js
function main() {
  var list = [
    ["feature 123", 5.0],
    ["feature 234", 38.0],
    ["feature 345", 38.0]
  ];
  var search = "feature 234";
  var a = getIndexx(list, search);
  console.log(a); // 1
}

function getIndexx(array, str) {
  for (var k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
    if (array[k][0] === str) {
      return k;
    }
  }
  return -1; // Should be the default condition
}

main();
```