# for loop stops after first iteration JS

Tags: javascript

so am doing this exercise where it asks me to return a list of strings for each counted number.

I am aware that the function will end as soon as it return a value. I tried couple of other variations such as continue and break, but i cant seem to figure it out.
Thank you in advance

```
var countSheep = function (num) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        return `${i}sheep...`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of returning in the loop, push the value onto an array. Then return the array at the end.

Comment: duplicate [Simple Javascript for loop stops after first iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63270962/simple-javascript-for-loop-stops-after-first-iteration)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Barmar, you can add the values to an array and return the list after the for loop completes. That would look like:

```js
var countSheep = function (num) {
  var list = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
      list.push(`${i}sheep...`);
  }
  
  return list
}

console.log(countSheep(3))
```